# Math in a NodeRed function block

Tags: node-red

I am trying to do a math function in a function-block in Node-RED but it can only handle easier task like multiply.

I am trying to do this function but it can't handle the exponents(^). Perhaps there is a math function or something to declare this? It just returns a wacko number as it is now.

```
msg.payload = (6*10^47)/(msg.payload^16.66);
return msg;
```

Comment: You do know that in C++ the operator `^` is the [bitwise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators) exclusive or operator? You are perhaps looking for the [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) function?

Comment: Hi, Node-RED uses javascript for its functions. Not sure how you are using C++?

Comment: You are right.. It is Javascript, so it should be Math.pow(msg.payload,16.66). Thought it was C++. But the principle were the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` operator doesn't do what you think it does, it's the bitwise XOR operator.

If you want to raise something to the power of x use `pow`:

```
#include <cmath>
std::pow(msg.payload, 16.66);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the cmath header which contains the pow function, in your case it would look something like:

```
#include <cmath>

msg.payload = (6*std::pow(10,47))/(std::pow(msg.payload,16.66));
return msg;
```

The number returned is the first parameter raised by the second.